# How to know the child count of a folder which is inside some Folder(fetching by folder id)?

Tags: google-api, google-drive-api

How to know the childcount of a folder in Result(fetching by folder id)?

Ex:

Main folder id is 123.

inside main folder i have 2 folders i.e `ABC` folder and `XYZ` folder.

```
---Root (123)
  |
  ------ ABC
  |
  ------  XYZ
```

Now my question is how to know the child count of `ABC` and `XYZ` folders.

By using one API call I want both information of `ABC` and `XYZ` along with child count.

Code:

```
https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v2/files?maxResults=1000&q='{main folder id}' in parents  and trashed = false)
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this endpoint?

```
GET https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v2/files?maxResults=1000&q='### folder ID of ABC ###'+in+parents+or+'### folder ID of XYZ ###'+in+parents+and+trashed%3Dfalse
```

#### Note :

- File information in both folders of "ABC" and "XYZ" is retrieved using `or` operator.
- When you use this, please input folder ID of "ABC" and "XYZ".
- Use of Drive API v2 is due to your sample.

If I misunderstand your question, I'm sorry.

Comment: while fetching main folder data using main folder id, how would i know the sub folder id's of main folder.

Comment: @raghava arr I'm sorry for the inconvenience. I thought that I may be misunderstanding what you want. You want to retrieve folder IDs on the root folder and files in the retrieved folders. You want to do both, simultaneously. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: No, i want information of sub folders and it's child count

Comment: @raghava arr Thank you for the additional information. I'm sorry for my poor English skill.

Answer (score 0):

[file.list](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/reference/files/list) returns a list of [file.resources](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/reference/files#resource).  When you build up your search you are looking for files with in a main directorie including only the two sub directories.  You are going to get a list back of these directories.

You can test this using [Google Apis Explorer](https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/drive/v3/drive.files.list?q='0B5pJkOVaKccEYW5lVHBKd1Zwc28'%20in%20parents%20and%20(name%20contains%20'backup'%20or%20name%20contains%20'2016-10-05')&fields=files(id%252Cname%252Cparents)&_h=15&)

```
GET https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files?q='{Id}'+in+parents+and+(name+contains+'{SEARCHONE}'+or+name+contains+'{SEARCHTWO}')&fields=files(id%2Cname%2Cparents)&key={YOUR_API_KEY}
```

1. `{id} in parents` will return only files within a parent directory this means that files in sub directories will not be returned
2. `(name+contains+'{SEARCHONE}'+or+name+contains+'{SEARCHTWO}')` will only return files that contain the search in the name.

Note: In my example i am using the v3 of the Google Drive API i suggest you use it if possible.   If its not possible then just change name to title and the query should work for oyu as well.

**Answer**

The Response does not include a count.  You will need to sum them yourself locally once you have the list down.   In order to save yourself some processing i would suggest you add `fields=files(id,parents)` to your request this way you are only returning the ids of your file and its parent you can then use this to create your count.

Comment: just i want child count of sub folder, i don't want information of sub folder of sub folder

Comment: @DalmTo using one api call i want information of sub folders and its child count

Comment: @raghavaarr I understand what you want you cant get a count back the data is not returned by the API. You will need to run the one request i have given you then sum them yourself in your code.   Again the API does not return child count you need to do that yourself.

Comment: @DalmTo Thank you

Comment: Let me know if you need anymore help the api can be hard to understand in the beginning good luck

Comment: @DalmTo sure i ll ask